# Rewriting multivariate second order diffrential equation as system of first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I hope someone can shed some light on the steps taken in between, as I have the answer and the problem, but no idea how to get there:

Given the second order differential equation

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0$$

by introducing: (1)
$$r = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \qquad p = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

One can get the following (2)

$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial t} - c^2 \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = 0$$

But how, I am stuck since this question involves 2 variables. - Shouldn't the solution contain 4 functions?

EDIT: my problem lays between going from step (1) to step (2). - *How* does one get the two functions then?

Comment: why should it contain 4 functions? It seems like you did the correct steps.

Comment: @Chinny84 updated the question for clarity...

Comment: I have added an answer is that what you were confused about, the derivation?

Answer (score 1):

So from 
$$
\partial_t u = r\\
\partial_x u = p.
$$
we find that
$$
\partial_t(\partial_t u) - c^2\partial_x(\partial_x u) = 0\\
\partial_t r - c^2 \partial_x p = 0.
$$
now we have
$$
\partial_x r =\partial_x(\partial_t u) = \partial_{xt}u\\
\partial_t p = \partial_t(\partial_x u) = \partial_{tx}u.
$$
for nicely behaved functions for $u$ we have
$$
 \partial_{tx}u =  \partial_{xt}u
$$
hence
$$
\partial_x r =\partial_t p  \implies \partial_t p - \partial_x r = 0
$$

Comment: Now I wonder still, is this a generic approach: can you "always" get the second equation necessary by integrating introduced functions (r, p in this case) to the other derivative, so making cross-derivative (dxdy / dydt / ..) terms? Is that a strategy one should do for solving these things?

Comment: I have not really solved things this way round. I have solved it the other way. By the other way I mean I have a set of coupled equations which I combine with applying the differential operators to obtain a single(or at least reduced set) governing equation. So starting with the two equations you have above and derive the wave equation to solve..does that make sense?

Comment: Well yes, but I don't have to do that. - My goal is to solve PDE's (hyperbolic ones to be specific) and for that I need to find the charasteristic boundary equations. - Which come from transforming the PDE into a set of ODEs

Comment: Ah ok then. This answer doesn't really do your question justice.